# Button enabled disabled intermittently

Tags: angularjs

I have a detailed price screen where upon selecting a particular product two buttons must become disabled they are namely previewpreseller and acceptpresellervalue. When I select that particular product it has preview and accept prePriceSeller buttons enabled at random. This happens whenever I change to other page and come back I find it enabled.

This is block of code in my controller which I believe is creating the issue. Not sure if I have coded something wrong.

```
$scope.checkPricingKeyConflict = function(){
            var request = {
                    "apiId":"priceService",
                    "methodName":"getPricingKeyConflictMessage",
                    "headerdata" : JSON.stringify($scope.currentQuote.headerData)                   
            }

            var doLater = function(response){
                if(response.message=='OK'){
                    if(response.items[0].messages && response.items[0].messages.length>0){
                        $scope.currentQuote.previewPrePriceDisabled = true;
                        $scope.currentQuote.acceptPrePriceDisabled = true;
                    }else{
                        $scope.currentQuote.previewPreSellerDisabled = false;
                        $scope.currentQuote.acceptPreSellerDisabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            $window.getCurrentContext().getDataService($window.getCurrentContext().getUrl('api/rest/get'),$http).get({params:request},doLater);
        }
```

My Html code for one of the buttons

```
<div class="ibm-small" style="float:left;padding-left:35px;padding-top:5px" data-ng-if=" ((appname=='PSAT' && currentQuote.quoteCustomer.vsmandatory=='Y')  || appname=='PCS' ) && !sp2user && (currentQuote.overViewData.geoCode=='AP' || currentQuote.overViewData.geoCode=='NA' || (currentQuote.overViewData.geoCode=='EM' && currentQuote.detailPricing.useAGOG=='Y' && currentQuote.detailPricing.vspDeployed=='Y') && currentQuote.detailPricing.dis=='N')">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="" data-ng-click="previewAddendum()" data-ng-class="{disabled: currentQuote.previewpresellerDisabled}">
                                    <svg class="icon icon-eye"><title>Preview Pre seller offer</title><use xlink:href="#icon-eye"></use></svg>
                                    <strong translate="Preview_Pre_Seller"></strong>                
        </button>
    </div>
```

My Pricing service Impl

```
public DataBean getPMAKeyConflictMessage(DataBean input) throws ServiceException{
            DataBean result = Helper.getResponseTemplate();
            DataBean items = new DataBean();
            Helper.addToParent(result, items, null);
            Long quoteid = Long.valueOf(Helper.parseJSON(input.getString("headerdata")).getString("id"));

            List<Ctmtwmsg> pMAKeyConflictMessages = quoteActionRepo.getAllWarningMessages(quoteid, "A");
            if(pMAKeyConflictMessages!= null && pMAKeyConflictMessages.size()>0){

                DataBean tempBean;
                for(Ctmtwmsg wmsg : pMAKeyConflictMessages){
                    tempBean = new DataBean();
                    tempBean.setValue("message", wmsg.getMsgdesc());
                    Helper.addToParent(items, tempBean, "messages");
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be certain whether the `.checkPricingKeyConflict` function is called when the page is activated. Then you need to determine if you are getting inside the `if(response.message=='OK')`. You probably sometimes are not getting there to set the values. But the logic you've submitted isn't complete enough to be sure.

I would recommend adding the following three `console.log` msgs, and view the results in your 'inspector' window when you activate the page.

```
$scope.checkPricingKeyConflict = function(){
        console.log("ENTERED FNC .checkPricingKeyConflict");
        var request = {
                "apiId":"priceService",
                "methodName":"getPricingKeyConflictMessage",
                "headerdata" : JSON.stringify($scope.currentQuote.headerData)                   
        }

        var doLater = function(response){
            if(response.message=='OK'){
                console.log("ENTERED if(response.message...");
                if(response.items[0].messages && response.items[0].messages.length>0){
                    $scope.currentQuote.previewPrePriceDisabled = true;
                    $scope.currentQuote.acceptPrePriceDisabled = true;
                }else{
                    $scope.currentQuote.previewPreSellerDisabled = false;
                    $scope.currentQuote.acceptPreSellerDisabled = false;
                }
                console.log("VALUES prvw,acpt:" $scope.currentQuote.previewPreSellerDisabled, $scope.currentQuote.acceptPreSellerDisabled);
            }
        }

        $window.getCurrentContext().getDataService($window.getCurrentContext().getUrl('api/rest/get'),$http).get({params:request},doLater);
    }
```

I think that will show you why you aren't enable/disabling the buttons on screen entry.

Good Luck!

Comment: I have changed "data-ng-class" in my html to "data-ng-disabled" and I am testing it now. So far it is working. Will do further more test to confirm the same. Thanks for sharing the information and this helped me acquire further knowledge about angularjs.